# How to store a NSArray into plist or database?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have this app which has to store information when I hit some button.. The fact is, when I hit this button I need to store this data locally so I can take this in other view which is going to load it at show it as data.

I'm thinking in some plis or database. The problem is I can't get to an idea or something good.

1. I pass the array with objects.
2. I have the button.

Which is the best way to store the entire array inside the phone, so I can read it as the same way it is stored?

If this is not clear, please tell me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easies way is to save it to a plist

Like this:

```
//create array
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Add data
[arr addObject:@"some object"];

//String Path of file
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

//Save
[arr writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Loading it later like this:

```
//Load it
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: Does it saves the data in a hidden plist?

Comment: Not hidden, why u want it hidden?

Comment: I have a plist in Directory Documents and it is called "Citys"... the information goes there?

Comment: It works only for strings array, not worked for custom objects array. :(

Comment: Couldn't write into existing plist file