# Generate plist data from NsArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a nsarray with objects. 
I want to use a api method that has a parameter that is a plist - xml containing the object from my array . Is there a method that creates plist / xml string from array ?

Example :

```
 My Object { int id ,NsString name }
 plist ..
 <array>
  <dict>
  <key> Id </key>
  <integer>1</integer>
 </dict>
 ...
..
</array>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store a NSArray into plist or database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880870/how-to-store-a-nsarray-into-plist-or-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to make "plist" File..

```
NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
{
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%d", i];
    NSInteger value = i;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInteger:value], key, nil];
    [testArray addObject:dictionary];
}

NSString *error;
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:(id)testArray
                                                      format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                            errorDescription:&error];

if(plistData)
{
    NSArray *documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *saveDir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/plistData.plist", [documentDirectoryPath objectAtIndex:0]];
    [plistData writeToFile:saveDir atomically:YES];

}else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

or you want to make "XML".. just change one line. 
like this.

```
NSString *saveDir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/plistData.xml", [documentDirectoryPath objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: i found it for get the xml string                                      NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:testArray format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:NSPropertyListImmutable error:&error];
 
 if (error == nil) {
  transformed = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plistData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 }
 else {
  NSLog(@"%@- error: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),error);
 }